# Problem with discretization of one-dimensional stationary Boltzmann equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

The free-streaming term in stationary 1D Boltzmann equation satisfies the equilibrium distribution function, that is:
\begin{equation}
\text{Fr}\{f\} := v(k)\dfrac{\partial f(x,k)}{\partial x} 
- \dfrac{d\varepsilon_\text{sub}(x)}{dx}\dfrac{\partial f(x,k)}{\partial k}
\end{equation} 
equals zero by putting $f_0(x,k) = \exp\left(-\dfrac{k^2}{2m}-\varepsilon_\text{sub}(x)\right)$, with $v(k)=\dfrac{k}{m}$.

However, after discretization:
\begin{equation}
\text{Fr}\{f(x_i,k_j)\} :=
\dfrac{k_j}{m}\Big[f(x_{i+1},k_j) - f(x_i,k_j)\Big] - 
\dfrac{\varepsilon_\text{sub}(x_{i+1})-\varepsilon_\text{sub}(x_i)}{\Delta x}  \Big[f(x_i,k_{j+1}) - f(x_i,k_j)\Big]
\end{equation}
the equilibrium function $f_0(x_i,k_j) = \exp\left(-\dfrac{k_j^2}{2m}-\varepsilon_\text{sub}(x_i)\right)$ no longer is a solution to our discretized equation (Of course, the solution gets closer and closer to the equilibrium distribution function by refining the grid).

Since it is a very important property for our discretization to satisfy $\text{Fr}\{f_0\} = 0$ by construction, could you suggest a suitable discretization scheme in this regard?